# Clickable Data Table Row

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, datatable

I am having a data table which is fetching its data from MySQL database. In my database i am having a column named as "location" which is a link to some audio file. All the rows in the database are having their respective links to their audio files.What i want is that

1. When i click on any row of the data table the browser should automatically get redirected to the link of their respective audio files.
2. The Current link that is stored in the database is for local IP. i want to change the link to my public IP before the user is redirected since the local IP won't work on remote server. Below is my code:

**data table.php**

```
 <?php
    /* Database connection start */
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "vici";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

    /* Database connection end */


    // storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
    $requestData= $_REQUEST;


    $columns = array( 
    // datatable column index  => database column name
        0 =>'recording_id', 
        1 => 'call_date',
        2=> 'location',
        3=> 'Agent',
        4=> 'phone'
    );

    // getting total number records without any search
    $sql = "SELECT recording_id, call_date, location,agent,phone";
    $sql.=" FROM goautodial_recordings_view";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");
    $totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.


    $sql = "SELECT recording_id, call_date, location,agent,phone";
    $sql.=" FROM goautodial_recordings_view WHERE 1=1";
    if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {   // if there is a search parameter, $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
        $sql.=" AND ( recording_id LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";    
        $sql.=" OR call_date LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
        $sql.=" OR agent LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";
    }
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");
    $totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result. 
    $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
    /* $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains colmun index, $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc  */    
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");

    $data = array();
    while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
        $nestedData=array(); 

        $nestedData[] = $row["recording_id"];
        $nestedData[] = $row["call_date"];
        $nestedData[] = $row["location"];
        $nestedData[] = $row["agent"];
        $nestedData[] = $row["phone"];

        $data[] = $nestedData;
    }



    $json_data = array(
                "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
                "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
                "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
                "data"            => $data   // total data array
                );

    echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

    ?>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>GO VOIP</title>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax":{
                        url :"employee-grid-data.php", // json datasource
                        type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                        error: function(){  // error handling
                            $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                            $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                            $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

                        }
                    }
                } );

            $('.dataTable').on('click', 'tbody td', function() {

  //get textContent of the TD
  alert('TD cell textContent : ', this.textContent)

  //get the value of the TD using the API 
  ('value by API : ', table.cell({ row: this.parentNode.rowIndex, column : this.cellIndex }).data());
})
            } );
        </script>
        <style>
            div.container {
                margin: 0 auto;
                max-width:760px;
            }
            div.header {
                margin: 100px auto;
                line-height:30px;
                max-width:760px;
            }
            body {
                background: #f7f7f7;
                color: #333;
                font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue",HelveticaNeue,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header"><h1>DataTable demo (Server side) in Php,Mysql and Ajax </h1></div>
        <div class="container">
            <table id="employee-grid"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Recording ID</th>
                            <th>Call date</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Agent</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Below is the Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Why don't you get the data using ajax directly ? and then add it to the table manually and finally initialize the datatable ?

Comment: Please explain how to do it @Kishor

Comment: Can i get the address of the server ? So that i could post a js fiddle.

Comment: @Amir the answer of your 2nd question
`UPDATE yourTable
SET feild_of_ip = REPLACE (feild_of_ip, 'localip', 'remoteip')
WHERE feild_of_ip LIKE '%localip%'`  
----

`UPDATE goautodial_recordings_view
SET location = REPLACE (location, 'http://192.168.0.164', 'http://233.465.23.34')
WHERE location LIKE '%http://192.168.0.164%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**method 1 :**
change in SQL query (only where you get rows not count)

```
$sql = "SELECT recording_id, call_date, CONCAT('<a href="',location,'">get song</a>'),agent,phone";
```

*note : if you have some field in mysql like song_name then you display in anchor tag*

```
$sql = "SELECT recording_id, call_date, CONCAT('<a href="',location,'">',song_name,'</a>'),agent,phone";
```

OR

**method 2 :**
change in PHP while loop
//replace from

```
$nestedData[] = $row["location"];
```

to

```
$nestedData[] = '<a href="'.$row["location"].'">get song</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in simple php with eco like:

```
echo '<a href="'.$stringwiththelink.'">Name of the song</a>';
```

If you click on it it will redirect you to the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "employee-grid-data.php",
        success: function(data){
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          /*Here you will get the data
            Loop through the data and append to dataTable*/
          $('#employee-grid').DataTable();
        },
        error : function() { // error handling
            $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
            $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
            $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display", "none");
          }
      });
```

Use ajax to get JSON data from the server and manually add it to the HTML table, finally initialize datatable.